Xdebug is not working CLI debugging way, but WEB debugging works
My setup is Windows + WSL2 + Ubuntu + Docker, I'm running a Symfony project. Web debugging works fine, for example when I open some page and trigger some function, it works. However, when I run some command from terminal, it does not work and specifically xdebug.log shows one related error I suppose, I masked it with ***:
[1873] [Step Debug] WARN: Breakpoint file name does not exist: //wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/root/www/****************************(No such file or directory).

What I found strange is that in Windows Explorer the path is with the backslashes:
\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\root\www\****************************

But Xdebug tries with forward slash and it fails, is the reason why Xdebug won't work from CLI could be this?
xdebug.ini
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log=xdebug.log
xdebug.log_lev=10
xdebug.discover_client_host=1

Nothing yet, I do not know from where to start.

PHP is smart enough to replace / with \\ on Windows as path separators
